# Bootstrap 3 - Full Height Side Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In my web page, I have a banner, which I do *not* want to fix (i.e. stick) to the top. Below the banner, I have my content, divided into two main parts: the text and related content.

The text is just a long block of text. The related content are some links. However, to set the related content apart, I'm trying to give it a gray background. I want that gray background to go the entire height of the page (minus the height of the banner). When a user scrolls, I want the gray background to stay in place, though the content might scroll. In other words, the long block of text and the related content do *not* scroll independently of each other.

For some reason, I've been unable to figure out how to get a gray background on my side panel. The height is off. I've been experimenting in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/O8dBTNYIwD). It has the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-title">
  <div class="container text-center text-title">
    <div>Welcome</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height:100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div style="padding:24px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

1914 translation by H. Rackham

"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make the sidebar fill the entire height of the screen (minus the height of the banner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some JavaScript to get the height of the document - the height of the sidebar.

Also, don't use empty DIVs with Bootstrap, there is no need. You can use the offset class. E.g. col-md-3 col-md-offset-1

```js
$('.sidebar').height(($(document).height() -$('.container-fluid.container-title').height()));
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.container-title {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #2D2D2D;
    height:72px;  
}
  
.text-title {
    padding-top:14px;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
}
    
.sidebar {
    background-color:#EEE;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid container-title">
  <div class="container text-center text-title">
    <div>Welcome</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height:100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div style="padding:24px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

1914 translation by H. Rackham

"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-3 sidebar">hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the right side "position:fixed" and set the heights accordingly. Since you want the sidebar 100% height, any containers of the sidebar (container-fluid, row, etc..) also need, to be full height. Use `calc(..)` to subtract the height of the top banner. You also probably want to use a media query to only fix the sidebar on large screens..

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .main>.row {
      height:calc(100% - 72px);
    }
    .sidebar {
        background-color:#EEE;
        height:100%;
        position: fixed;
        right:0;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/u3BEJsj05v